# VBA Excel Auto Filter Column based on cell contents

Tags: excel, vba

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$5000").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>"
```

I am working on a VBA project in which I need to auto filter a large field.  As you can see from the code above, I am filtering the 17 field or column.  I would like the code to look at the value in cell A1 to determine the field/column to filter.   For example, if cell A1 said 15 i would like to filter by Field 15.   So if I haven't made my self clear, I am wanting to substitute Field:=17 in the code with something like Field:=(Cell A1 Value)

Comment: You basically already have the answer: `Field:=Range("A1").Value`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that has been asked here and found out the solution. Could be helpful, if someone come looking

Use the Column Property of the Range Object to get the column number of a specific cell you are interested in.

In the above case:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AK$5000").AutoFilter Field:=Range("A1").Column, Criteria1:="<>"
```